# How do I edit places in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I want to add additional info of my town. Currently I have the 'edit details' options disabled. The Video tutorial & help pages are out dated with older version of Google Maps. What should I do to enable the setting?

Comment: What do you mean by _edit options_ are disabled?

Comment: if you are search for a place, you will get a 'A' Marker over that place and click more-> edit details. The reason i'm asking for edit option is i've few contact details & some more that i want to update.

Comment: The edit options are enabled on a _per country_ basis and may be dependent on the relationship of the data providers with Google. What country are you trying to edit places?

Comment: its a place in india.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you mean by you have edit options disabled...

But to edit a places details you do the following:

1. Go onto the places page and click *'edit this place'*
   [image: Edit this place]
2. Now you can edit the places details.

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted but if it's not please edit your answer with a better explanation to the problem and then comment on this answer.

Comment: I don't have that button. i don't know if they support that feature in india.

Comment: Maybe it isn't then. India may have certain rules or something, not quite sure.

Comment: I wouldn't chalk this up to "certain rules" in India. It's more likely that Google simply hasn't rolled out this feature in India yet.